# Having issue retaining multi checked box value php

Tags: php, arrays, validation, input, checked

Am having trouble retaining the value for my multi checked box array. Have look on this site and have applied the answer to mine, but for some reason is not keeping the checked value. ** here is my PHP **

```
       <?php

    // start session
    session_start();

    // i user is not log in redirect back to index
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_type'])){
      header('Location: index.php');
    }

    // include data based connection config
    include_once('include/connection.php');

    // incluude header ttile page
    $title  = "Edit User Profile";

    // set user session variables
    $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    //$userName = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $temp = $_SESSION['user_name'];

    //$competency = "";
    // if user update the data
      if(isset($_POST['update'])){

       // define post variable
    $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $user_name = trim($_POST['user_name']);
    $profession = trim($_POST['profession']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $hobbies = trim($_POST['hobbies']);
    $skills = trim($_POST['skills']);
    $competency = implode(', ', $_POST['competency']);
    $postcode = trim($_POST['postcode']);
    $address = trim($_POST['address']);
    $bio = trim($_POST['bio']);  
    $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);
    $gender = trim($_POST['gender']);
    $country = trim($_POST['country']);


          // ************* UPDATE PROFILE INFORMATION ************************//
          if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE user SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?, skills = ?, competency = ?, profession = ?, 
          user_name = ?, phone = ?, address = ?, email = ?, bio = ?,
          gender = ?, dob = ?, country = ? WHERE id = ?"))) {
              echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
          }
          if(!$stmt->bind_param('ssssssissssssi', $firstname, $lastname, $skills, $competency, $profession, 
                                $user_name, $phone, $address, $email, $bio, 
                                $gender, $dob, $country, $userId)){
            echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
                  }
          if(!$stmt->execute()){
                   echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
                  }


                  if($stmt) {
                      $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Successfully Updated!";
                                   header('Location: profile.php');
                                      exit;

                  }else{
                          $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Some error, try again";
                          header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                      }

           $stmt->close();



      }

                $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, skills, competency, user_name, avatar, profession, email, dob, gender, country, phone, bio, address, created_at FROM user WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $userId);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();  
            if($stmt->num_rows == 0) {  
                echo 'No Data Found for this user';
            }else {
                $stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $skills, $competency, $user_name, $avatar, $profession, $email, $dob, $gender, $country, $phone, $bio, $address, $created_at);
                $stmt->fetch();

              $stmt->close();

            }
                ?>
```

*** And here is my HTML ***

```
       <div class="user-details">

      <form name="update" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">

    <table>
    <label for="">Avatar</label>
    <input name="ImageFile" type="file" id="uploadFile"/>
    <!--                     <div>
      <div class="shortpreview">
          <label for="">Previous Avatar </label>
          <br> 
          <img src="userfiles/avatars/<?php //echo $avatar;?>" width='150' height='150' >
      </div>
    </div> -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="shortpreview" id="uploadImagePreview">
          <label for="">Current Uploaded Avatar </label>
          <br> 
          <div id="imagePreview"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </table>


        <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Update</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">First Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"  value ="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"></td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Skills</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="skills" name="skills"  value ="<?php echo $skills; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>        
    <label >Competency:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="RRT" name="competency[]" <?php if(isset($_POST['competency']) && in_array('RRT', $_POST['competency'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>RRT<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="ESD" name="competency[]" <?php if(isset($_POST['competency']) && in_array('ESD', $_POST['competency'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>ESD<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="SDT" name="competency[]" <?php if(isset($_POST['competency']) && in_array('SDT', $_POST['competency'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>SDT<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="CAR" name="competency[]" <?php if(isset($_POST['competency']) && in_array('CAR', $_POST['competency'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>CAR <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="DH" name="competency[]" <?php if(isset($_POST['competency']) && in_array('DH', $_POST['competency'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>DH<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="MEDS" name="competency[]" <?php if(isset($_POST['competency']) && in_array('MEDS', $_POST['competency'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>MEDS <br>

    <!--                    <input type="checkbox"  value="RRT" name="competency['RRT']" <?php// if(!empty($_POST['competency']['RRT'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>>RRT<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="ESD" name="competency['ESD']" <?php //if(!empty($_POST['competency']['ESD'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>>ESD<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="SDT" name="competency['SDT']" <?php //if(!empty($_POST['competency']['SDT'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>>SDT<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="CAR" name="competency['CAR']" <?php //if(!empty($_POST['competency']['CAR'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>>CAR<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="MEDS"  name="competency['MEDS']" <?php// if(!empty($_POST['competency']['MEDS'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>>MEDS<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="DH"  name="competency['DH']" <?php //if(!empty($_POST['competency']['DH'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>>DH<br> -->
    </td>
    </tr>
    <!--         <tr>        
    <td> 

    <select name="competency[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="SDT">SDT</option>
    <option value="ESD">ESD</option>
    <option value="CAR">CAR</option>
    <option value="MEDS">MEDS</option>
    <option value="DH">DH</option>
    </select>

    </td>
    </tr> -->

        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">User Nmae</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Profession Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="profession" name="profession" value="<?php echo $profession; ?>"></td>
        </tr>                            

        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Phone</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></td>
        </tr>                           

         <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Email</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Gender</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="gender" name="gender" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Date Of Birth</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Addres</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"></td>
          </tr>


        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Country</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>"></td>
        </tr>  


        <tr>
        <td><label for = "">Bio</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bio" name="bio" value="<?php echo $bio; ?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td></td>               
        <td><input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </form>       
    </div>
```

Here is my updated code hopefully there is something causing it.

Comment: First you have `$_POST['competency']` then you have just `$competency`. Did you define `$competency` anywhere?

Comment: yes i have that already here `$competency = implode(', ', $_POST['competency']);` i used this to post to database

Comment: in_array does not work on strings. It works on arrays, as the name suggests.

Comment: ok what is the best way to the check value retained, if you look at my HTML the first and second have used another atempt

Comment: You need to understand what the code does instead of just copying and pasting from other places. `isset($_POST['competency'])` returns true if `$_POST['competency']` exists, but it can be any value. Likewise `!empty($_POST['competency'])` will return true if it exists and is not empty. And as I mentioned above, in_array does not work on strings.

Comment: Personally I would probably put the variable name right in the HTML: `<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="competency['RRT']" <?php if(!empty($_POST['competency']['RRT'])) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>>RRT<br>`

Comment: @Mike... Thanks, and just for the record i do understand what the code do, i was just fraustrated that have spent hours figuring it out. allow me to check with your suggestion code

Comment: @Mike... am sorry for the delay in response, have tried your code suggestion, but still the same problem, maybe i should paste all my code here and you can see where the issue might have come from.

Comment: If it didn't work, make sure you refresh the form page before submitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (updated) :

```
<?php $competency = explode(', ', $competency); ?>
<tr>
    <td>        
            <label >Competency:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="RRT" name="competency[]" <?php if(is_array($competency) && in_array('RRT', $competency)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>RRT<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="ESD" name="competency[]" <?php if(is_array($competency) && in_array('ESD', $competency)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>ESD<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="SDT" name="competency[]" <?php if(is_array($competency) && in_array('SDT', $competency)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>SDT<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="CAR" name="competency[]" <?php if(is_array($competency) && in_array('CAR', $competency)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>CAR <br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="DH" name="competency[]" <?php if(is_array($competency) && in_array('DH', $competency)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>DH<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="MEDS" name="competency[]" <?php if(is_array($competency) && in_array('MEDS', $competency)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>MEDS <br>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Also make sur that your form method is post:

```
<form methos="POST" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, my method is post, i will also try your as well.

Comment: am sorry for the delay in response, have tried your code suggestion, but still the same problem, please watch out for my updated code, maybe you might see where the issue lies

Comment: check the updated code

Comment: hi what's the update, i can't any different.

Comment: hi Okba... it worked! but what i don't get is have already define the variable above `<?php $competency = explode(', ', $competency); ?>` why do need it twice.

Comment: Great ! the first one, you used implode function, and the second one is explode, which is the opposite of the first one, learn more about both functions here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php and http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php